# Which dependency should be added in order to use "edit" extention for SharePreferences?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am following the example described here - https://medium.com/@helmersebastian/clean-sharedpreferences-in-android-using-kotlin-delegation-ffabffd26990

Following this implementation I added `DefaultSharedPrefs`

```
var sharedApplicationContext: Context
    get() = _sharedApplicationContext
        ?: throw IllegalStateException(
            "Application context not initialized yet."
        )
    set(value) {
        _sharedApplicationContext = value
    }

private var _sharedApplicationContext: Context? = null
private val PREF_NAME = "pref_name"

object DefaultSharedPrefs : SharedPreferences by sharedApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
    PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
)
```

Usage suppose to be like this

```
class Foo {
...
    private var DefaultSharedPrefs.count: Int
        get() = getInt("key", 0)
        set(value) = edit { putInt("key", value) }
...
}
```

However I get such an error

[image]

So, looks like the problem or I missed some dependency or I use the wrong one.

After some reserch I found out that I missed this class

````
package androidx.core.content

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.SharedPreferences

/**
 * Allows editing of this preference instance with a call to [apply][SharedPreferences.Editor.apply]
 * or [commit][SharedPreferences.Editor.commit] to persist the changes.
 * Default behaviour is [apply][SharedPreferences.Editor.apply].
 * ```
 * prefs.edit {
 *     putString("key", value)
 * }
 * ```
 * To [commit][SharedPreferences.Editor.commit] changes:
 * ```
 * prefs.edit(commit = true) {
 *     putString("key", value)
 * }
 * ```
 */
@SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
public inline fun SharedPreferences.edit(
    commit: Boolean = false,
    action: SharedPreferences.Editor.() -> Unit
) {
    val editor = edit()
    action(editor)
    if (commit) {
        editor.commit()
    } else {
        editor.apply()
    }
}
````

from here - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/package-summary

Then I tried to add this dependency

```
implementation "androidx.core.content:1.0.0"
```

but I still get the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_version"`

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list#dependency_6